# ASP.NET MVC download csv file through modal popup

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to download a csv file through asp.net mvc controller, but since I need user to make a selection input via dropdown list, I created a bootstrap modal pop-up.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "modal-form" }))
{
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("locationTypeId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.DropDownList("locationTypeId", Model.LocationList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
}
```

Once user clicks Save button, it would post to the controller as such:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(DefaultViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var repository = new SqlRepository(model);
            // go about creating csv file

            // returns byte[]
            var output = repository.CreateShipmentDataUpload();

            //DownloadCSV();
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
        }
    }

    return PartialView("_Create", model);
}
```

I'm not sure if I can/should call DownloadCSV() there. Here's the DownloadCSV():

```
public FileContentResult DownloadCSV(byte[] byteArray)
{
    return File(byteArray, "text/csv", "report.csv");
}
```

And here's the ajax success function call:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">

    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#modalDialog').modal('hide');
                        // Refresh:
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        $('#modalContent').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
</script>
}
```

How do I get to download the csv file to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take the form control out of the modal popup
2. Make your modal submit button call js script to close modal and fire ajax call back Download CSV method on the controller passing in the selection they made on the modal dropdown (get their selection by getting val of field by the elements ID
3. Do the byte parsing logic and return file in Download CSV method

The big idea around modal pop-ups and such is not to kill your user with page reloads. You've taken care of all of the hard work already with the modal popup and an ajax call, then your firing off a page load at the end. That's like running a race then sitting down 5 feet in front of the finish line.

Example

Test class to show in dropdown:

```
public class Whatever
{
    public int locationTypeId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Methods:

```
    public ActionResult Wut()
    {
        Whatever wut = new Whatever();
        wut.Locations = new List<SelectListItem>();
        wut.Locations.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Uno", Value = "1" });
        wut.Locations.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dos", Value = "2" });
        return View(wut);
    }
    public FileContentResult DownloadCSV(string location)
    {
        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("Generate, CSV, LOGIC, HERE, DEPENDING, ON, LOCATION"), "text/csv", "Example" + DateTime.Now.ToString("_MM-dd-yyyy-mm-ss-tt") + ".csv");
    }
```

View:

```
    @model DeleteMeWeb.Controllers.Whatever
    <div class="btn btn-primary" id="showModal">Show Modal</div>

    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id='myModal'>
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.DropDownList("locationTypeId", Model.Locations, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="btn btn-primary" id="fire">Save changes</div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    @section scripts
    {
        <script>
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $('#showModal').click(function () { $('#myModal').modal('show'); });
            $('#fire').click(function (){
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                //FIRE GET REQUEST WHEN RETURNING A FILE IT WILL FORCE DOWNLOAD WITHOUT PAGE NAVIAGTION
                window.location = "/Home/DownloadCSV?location=" + $('#locationTypeId').val();
            });
        </script>
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this, but first of all why do I need to take the form control? did you mean the @class = "form-control" ?

Comment: @joegreentea no, I am saying to remove the html form, you don't need it. See the example i added. Also note that when you are returning a file from your controller, you can just do a window.location request and instead of navigation it will force the file download.

Comment: thanks, it became clearer with an example you provided. And also you simplified the modal form and yes I don't need location.relaod()

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a `Json` response and a `FileContentResult` with the same `Ajax` call. You can either:-

1. Send the $.ajax request to carry out form validation (before creating the file for download), and if the validation is ok ($.ajax success), then send another "fire and forget" request to create and download the form using a `FileContentResult` action from within the original `$.ajax success` function. Or
2. Just send the "fire and forget" and return an empty file (or no file) if the validation fails.

Both scenarios allow you to close the modal in a controlled way without reloading the page; the `FileContentResult` simply downloads the file without affecting the View.

One way of carrying out a "fire and forget" is:

```
var data = { id: "someId" };
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "GET");
form.setAttribute("action", "url/to/DownloadCSV");
if (data != null && data.constructor === Object) {
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", data[key]);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }
}
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
form.remove();
```

This would go (or be referenced) in the `if (result.success) { }` part of the $.ajax request (if you intend to validate), along with `$('#modalDialog').modal('hide');` (but not `location.reload();`)

The file download action would then be something like:

```
public FileContentResult DownloadCSV(string someParameterToMakeTheFileIfNeeded)
{
    // Make the file and then return the FileContentResult here
    return File(byteArray, "text/csv", "report.csv");
}
```

There are different ways to skin this cat, and it's worth researching what's out there, but I find this works for me.